# Can't show non-modal Excel Progress Bar

Tags: excel, vba

why error in userform : Can't show non-modal form when modal form is displayed
this just work in ActiveX controls CommandButton

```
Option Explicit
' Written by Philip Treacy, June 2016
' http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-progress-bar-for-vba
Sub InitProgressBar(MaxValue As Long)
    With ProgressBar
    
        .BarColor.Tag = .BarBorder.Width / MaxValue
        .BarColor.Width = 0
        .ProgressText = ""
        .Show vbModeless
        
    End With
    
End Sub
Sub CloseProgressBar()
    Unload ProgressBar
    
End Sub
Sub ShowProgress(Progress As Long)
    With ProgressBar
        'Round Up
        .BarColor.Width = Round(.BarColor.Tag * Progress, 0)
        .ProgressText.Caption = Round((.BarColor.Width / .BarBorder.Width * 100), 0) & "% complete"
    
    End With
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dWeO.jpg)

Comment: That means you cannot show a form modeless `vbModeless` while another form is shown modal `vbMode`. Therfore the other form shown needs to be modeless too.

Comment: This is quite obvious: If you have a Modal form open, it prevents selecting anything else from Excel - eg the sheet. A Non-Modal form, however, would allow that. When you could open the 2nd form Non-Modal: How should Excel react when you try to select any sheet? Allow that? Or not?

Comment: FIX : select UserForm and ShowModal=False